# SEPA Mandate not visible on Contact anymore

Tags: permissions, roles

I have recurring sepa mandates on contacts (Members) but I can't see them while looking at the contacts.
The mandates are working and I can create the XML Export for the bank.
From the contact I can select the 'create SEPA mandate' Action but i can't see existing mandates.
I think the problem started after updating civicrm.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Exchnage Hans-Christian.

The latest version of CiviCRM contains changes regarding the display of custom tabs in the contact view that also affect CiviSEPA. You should be able to fix the described issue by upgrading to the latest CiviSEPA version (1.5): https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/releases

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will do the update and report back here.

Answer (score 0):

we're having the same issue even with 1.5 on CiviCRM 5.44 (see this [issue](https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/issues/626))

Comment: You may want to try a new release such as this one: https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/releases/tag/1.6-alpha2

Comment: thanks Andrea, we'll give a try and a feedback

Comment: we still have this issue. I've opened a ticket in github: https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepa/issues/626